# Multiplying each element in a h5py dataset

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, h5py

I have a h5py dataset, I want to create a new dataset which is the same shape as the original dataset but with each element multiplied by a float k.

`#original is h5py dataset, of size (2,2)`

`original.shape = (2,2)`

`new = k * original`

Is what I tried, but I get the following error message:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Dataset'

and I can't find information online. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?  Was there an error?  If not an error, what did it do, or not?

Comment: Thanks I edited it

Comment: Try downloading the dataset, that is: `arr = original[:]`.  `arr` is a numpy array that can do the multiplication.  `h5py` documentation is your friend.

Comment: Cheers! I didn't think this would work because of the large datasets I'm working with, but it did.

Comment: If the dataset is too large you can load a slice, multiplying and saving that.  The basic point is that a dataset isn't a  numpy array, and doesn't implement math methods.  But it does implement things like indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very short example that shows how it works.
First it creates a file with dset `orig_dset`.
It closes, then reopens and creates 2 new datasets with the original multiplied by `k=10`.
Note: `new_dset1` and `new_dset2` are identical. The second is created in a single line.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random((2,2)) 
k = 10.0

with h5py.File('SO_65999147.h5', mode='w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset('orig_dset', data=arr)
           
with h5py.File('SO_65999147.h5', mode='a') as h5f:
    orig_ds_arr = h5f['orig_dset'][:]
    new_ds_arr  = k * orig_ds_arr 
    h5f.create_dataset('new_dset1', data=new_ds_arr)
    h5f.create_dataset('new_dset2', data=k*h5f['orig_dset'][:])
```